# folders css and img content disappeared after KnpPaginatorBundle installation

Tags: symfony, knppaginator

folders css and img content disappeared after KnpPaginatorBundle installation

> C:\wamp\www...\web\bundles\app\css
>
> C:\wamp\www...\web\bundles\app\images

I installed KnpPaginatorBundle using composer and command `require knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle`

folder `C:\wamp\www\...\web\bundles` modification date is `2015-08-14 15:08` and

folder `C:\wamp\....\vendor\knplabs` modification date is `2015-08-14 15:04`

the modification date is my main clue. It was 8 days ago so I do not remember what else could have caused disappearance.

one other thing. All folders inside `\bundle` that modification date are `2015-08-14 15:08` became shortcut folder windows icon but they imitate shortcuts as they path does not change. (do you understand me people?)

apparently my files were removed from my disc as windows did not find them.

symfony project windows search files sorted by modification date:
[image: symfony project windows search files sorted by modification date]

what the heck?

Comment: `php app/console assets:install`

Comment: thanks for reply. This command did not reanimated these files. (folders are not shortcuts anymore, but contents are still empty)

Comment: You didn't by chance store your original files to `bundles`, didn't you? In that case, any of `assets:install --symlink` could have wiped your files :-/

Comment: ok, i got the problem now. What a shame.(I have some, not most recent one, version of css saved, its not the blackest nightmare)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assets should stay in the Resources/public/ folder of your bundle (http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/bundles.html#bundle-directory-structure). That way, during assets install, all the resources will be correctly copied or symlinked (according to the provided parameters).

Each time you use composer to install or update a package a series of post install commands is launched. One of these install all the assets using a similar version of the above command.

If you had your assets only in the web/bundles folder, there is no way you can recover them (unless you had a backup). One piece of advice is to use a local (or, even better, remote) Git Repository so that the risk of losing data is minimized. See here for details: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/workflow/new_project_git.html